# Collectionview no hide under NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, navigationbar

I have a problem with CollectionView scroll. The cells go on the status bar because the navigation bar no hides its.

Visit https://streamable.com/97kd9 for the video error

This is the image of CollectionView:

[image]

I changed the collection view and uncheck "Adjust scroll view inset" but nothing.
Sticky my navbar in viewdidload but this did not solve the problem
this is the code for sticky:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make collection view content clip to its bounds.

```
collectionView.clipsToBounds = true
```

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds)